# my "run self test" is not working while installing SMTP Pro Email extention..i face following error msg

Tags: magento-1.8

SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: test@test.com from: owner@example.com. Unable to send test email.
Exception message was: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 cn1sm79814635pad.11 - gsmtp
Please check the user guide for frequent error messages and their solutions.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Testing failed, please review the reported problems and if you need further help visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.

**UPDATE AFTER USE CUSTOM SMTP[![i got this error][2]][2]**
thank u in advance

[image: UPDATE AFTER USE CUSTOM SMTP]

Comment: can anyone help me to fix this issue...

Comment: Did you check the username and password from admin panel?

Comment: yes i checked twice

Comment: please Refere this link I have Same Problem ... [check this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102842/smtp-email-sending-errors)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your username and password of the smptppro configuration wrong.
[image]

Please provide the correct information. Definitely it will work.
Cheers

**UPDATE**

Use **Custom SMTP**(Email Connection) and use this [link](http://www.motobit.com/util/gmail-smtp-pop-outlook.asp) to give value for host,port

Comment: i used 'Google Apps or Gmail' for Email connecton

Comment: can you paste your config setting as image how i did above?

Comment: image added..pls check it

Comment: use the Custom SMTP option.

Comment: but i should use 'Google Apps or Gmail' option

Comment: i update my ques..pls check it

Comment: did u used custom SMTP method?if yes what is the host and port u assign?

Comment: yes.i used localhost.port is 465

Comment: can you check this link for gmail and test http://www.motobit.com/util/gmail-smtp-pop-outlook.asp